# If a pineapple is actually a berry then can it be grafted onto another berry tree?

Tags: grafting, berries

Same would be the case for avocados, watermelon, bananas, and pumpkins that are also classified as berries. Can they all be grafted onto one another?

Answer (score 4):

No, you can not graft a pineapple to another "**berry**" tree. This is because the fruit name "**berry**" is merely a botanical term for a "**type of fruit**" that the plant produces. The term "**berry**" has *nothing to do with how related the plants are to each other*.

There are dozens of botanical terms for "**different types of fruits**". But, not to be overly technical, these different terms are only given to describe what parts of the "**pericarp**" develop into what we *commonly refer to as the fruit of the plant*. They do not describe anything about how the plants are related to each other. *Only plants closely related to each other can be grafted together*. Here are a couple of botanical terminology links that provide more detailed information.

https://awkwardbotany.com/2014/10/04/22-botanical-terms-for-fruits/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit